# QTreeView: show "empty view" item?

Tags: qt, qt5, qtreeview, qstandarditemmodel

I want to show an item "There are no elements in this view" if the connected `QTreeView` model (set by `QSortFilterProxyModel`) has no elements to show.

How can I implement such things?

Thanks for small hints.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the solution is overriding the tree view's paint event and draw the custom text when there is no items in the view. You need to sub class the `QTreeView` in the following way:

```
class TreeView : public QTreeView
{
[..]
protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent * event)
    {
        if (model() && model()->rowCount() > 0) {
            QTreeView::paintEvent(event);
        } else {
            // If no items draw a text in the center of the viewport.
            QPainter painter(viewport());
            QString text(tr("There are no elements in this view"));
            QRect textRect = painter.fontMetrics().boundingRect(text);
            textRect.moveCenter(viewport()->rect().center());
            painter.drawText(textRect, Qt::AlignCenter, text);      
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, it works as expected :)

Have tried to solve this problem by adding a "hidden" element in the first row of model, and show it by checking the row count by the proxy model - but it's useless lot of code to implement, and it didnt works as i need that :/